What is the best way to eliminate High humidity levels in 1914 home
We have a dirt crawl space, we have placed vents on one side of house and an crawl space vent fan on the other to try and lower humidity, my kitchen cabinets are swelling and have mold, I have purchased 2 smaller dehumidifiers which seem to be pulling water however it's not fixing the problem. It's like a science project in my cabinets, I clean them 2 days later it's back. I don't know who to call or what to do. Do I leave the AC fan on all the time?

If you have A/C, you can ask your HVAC company if they can change the configuration to reduce the humidity.
There are whole house dehumidifiers that you can add to reduce humidity (also an HVAC company).
If the outside humidity is higher than the inside humidity, you can try calling in an insulation company to air-seal the house.  That may also require adding more ventilation, e.g. a Heat Recovery Ventilator.  Some of those try to capture excess humidity as well.  Note that if the inside humidity is higher than the outside, air-sealing will make the problem worse, not better.
Depending on the climate of your location, you might add a vapor barrier in your exterior walls.  You want the vapor barrier to catch condensation, so (quoting from that link)

Since warm, moisture-laden air seeks to flow toward colder temperatures, if you live in a hot climate and use air conditioning, your vapor barrier should be closer to the exterior of the structure. Conversely, if you live in a cold region, the barrier should be closer to the inner surface of the exterior wall.

Replacing the exterior-most layer is not uncommon.  You tend to have to do it about as often as you replace a roof.  The interior-most layer (drywall or whatever) is less common.  Therefore, it is often easier to add the appropriate vapor barrier in hot climates.  It remains possible in cooler climates.  Whether you take that step is up to you.  This would tend to be done by a general contractor or a siding company (in hot climates) or a drywall specialist (cooler climates).
